# Where to get jars for PayPal Classic API SDKs?

Tags: paypal

Looking at GitHub, how do I download the jars for the PayPal Classic API? The docs say to copy from the lib folder but I can only find the src? I must be downloading from the wrong place? But I can't find the right place.

Comment: Common guys. Rather than voting it down, could you not just answer it? I know it should be easy. But I must be suffering some mental block. I don't want the liability of building it. I want the official released jars. I know they must be here somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [SDK Index](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#merchant), there is a download link at the bottom. It is a zip file that contains all of the JAR files needed.